# how i can pass header and parmas togther in delete method using ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

how i can pass header and parms toghther in delete method in ionic 3 ? i am always getting a error like :-Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

```
  deleteSingleitem(params, header) {
    // console.log("option+++++", options)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.delete(this.url + "cart", params,header).subscribe(
        res => {
          // console.log(res, "res");
          if (res['success'] != 0) {
            resolve(res);
          }
          else {
            reject(res);
          }
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the dependency '@ionic-native/http' you should be doing it this way:

```
this.http.delete(this.url + "cart", {
    params: myParams,
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'headerKey': value
    })
  }
)
```

Try this out and comment if you achieve it.

Comment: I am getting this issue too...
Can you please share the example for request body?
Waiting for your suggestion.

Comment: i am getting error ,invaild request body , can you please share an example ? waiting for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the late, the answer that I gave was for the particular dependency located in @ionic-native/http or for the dependency "@angular/http" (which I prefeer), but for your case try something different instead: Import the HTTP from '@ionic-native/http/ngx'
. Like this `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx'`. And then use passing three parameters like you were doing.